# Best approximation of $\int f(x,y) \mathrm{d}\mu$ with an independent distribution $\tilde{\mu}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, optimization

Let us consider a distribution $\mu$ of a random vector $(X,Y)$. For simplicity, assume that both $X,Y$ take values in $[0,1]$ interval. We are also given a function $f$  $-$ let it be for instance  $f(x,y)=|x-y|^2$. Let me underline, that we do not assume anything about the distribution $\mu$. Now, the question is: can we say anything about
$$\inf_{\tilde{\mu}} \ \Bigg| \ \int f(x,y)\ \mathrm{d}\mu \ - \ \int \ f(x,y) \ \mathrm{d}\tilde\mu \Bigg|,$$
where infimum is taken over all distributions $\tilde{\mu}$ of $(\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y})$ with values in $[0,1]^2$, such that $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ are independent?

In other words, is there some theorem or a well known way of constructing the best "independent" approximation of a random vector $(X,Y)$ (given some target function $f$)?

I will be glad for any insight, link to relevant paper or a book.

Comment: This is probably not what you are looking for, but for the particular function $f(x,y)=|x-y|^2$ you could just choose $\bar{X} \sim X-Y$ and $\bar{Y} = 0$.

Comment: You are right, but I have forgotten to add a natural condition that $\tilde{\mu}$ is also a distribution on $[0,1]^2$.